# Limit a VPN server's services to VPN connections only

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, vpn

I have a jump server and I want to put it behind a VPN, I do not want to deploy a separate VPN server and put my jump server behind it. I thought of installing OpenVPN directly onto my jump server and allow connections to it only through VPN client.

I have installed OpenVPN and OpenVPN access server in it, I could see the server is healthy from the access server UI. Now how can I provide access to the VPN server only through a VPN?

I know this is a bit confusing and I didn't put it well, my apologies.

Appreciate any humble help.

Comment: I wonder how I managed to answer this question. There's not a word about SSH. Did you mean just SSH access or some other access too?

Comment: For now, I am only configuring it for ssh. What if I have to do for all other access? any directions? I ready to go read.

Comment: I just updated my answer to cover wider. You might also use a firewall, which might be easier or more difficult, depending on your skills.

Comment: Thanks again, I will take it further from here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SSH access, just limit the SSHD to a certain address. There should be a line like:

```
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

in you SSHD config file, probably `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Change 0.0.0.0 to your VPN server's VPN IP, uncomment the line, save the file, relaod SSHD and there you go.

For services other than SSH, you have to do a similar thing with them.

Using firewall control instead is another option. You can also apply both.

Comment: VPN server's IP is a public one, everyone can hit the public IP even if I change the sshd's listen address right? sorry I'm a newbie playing with aws for learning purpose.

Comment: @VigneshSP I don't have any VPN server at the moment, but if you run `ip a` on the server, you should see its VPN IP, as far as I can remember. It should have two IPs then.

Comment: yo it worked, thanks a lot :)